# The most efficient way to clone a new WPF control?

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

I have a grid in the application. From the profiling result, there are a lot of expenses on loading templates for the rows and cells. Each row has the same template, so I'm thinking about how to make clones by the row prototype.

I know there's a way like serializing the control with `XamlWriter`/`BamlWriter` and then deserialize by the readers, but the profiling result also shows applying template is mostly doing the same thing.

[image: Profiling result]

Is there a faster way to clone WPF controls? I'm thinking if there's a way of cloning via binary serialization?

Comment: Is the grid virtualized? If not should look into that if not all items are visible simultaneously.

Comment: @H.B. Yes, only visible rows are created.

Comment: Hmm, can't help you then, never optimized beyond that.